Retrieving Generated Data From Azure ML
I am having a very difficult time trying to download a JSON file from a successful Azure ML pipeline job. In the pic below you can see the contents of the saved file. However using the Python SDK, whether it be on the job or the run - the only files it shows me are the logs.

Several of the attempts have looked like:
run = Run.get(ws, job_name)
run.download_file(name=f"{output_file_name}", output_file_path=os.path.join(output_dir, output_file_name))

and
ml_client.jobs.download(
    name=job.name,
    download_path='./',
    output_name="portfolio_weights.json"
)

These return nothing or error out.
I will note, Data Outputs has the file in there but if I go to open it in blobstore it shows no results.
The pipeline job code to save the file looks like:
    output_dir = os.environ.get("AZUREML_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY",'outputs')
output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir,'portfolio_weights.json')

# Convert portfolio weights to a list and save as JSON
portfolio_weights_list = portfolio_weights.tolist()
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(portfolio_weights_list, f)

run.log("portfolio_weights_path", output_file_path)

run.upload_file(name="portfolio_weights.json", path_or_stream=output_file_path)

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

are you checking correct blobstore? please check it once again.

There is lot of ways you can download artifacts, but most important is you need to give the job name correctly.
Because a single job consists of many child jobs the output you are looking will be from that child job.
Here is the sample job i am having.

The child job train_pytorch_model is having the outputs, so get that job name or run id.

and outputs

To download full output folder use below code.
ml_client.jobs.download(name="ce359cbb-1d68-4fc6-bde5-43ff35620897",download_path="./")

The outputs and logs will be downloaded to artifacts folder.

Or using mlflow you download.
import  mlflow
mlflow.artifacts.download_artifacts(run_id="ce359cbb-1d68-4fc6-bde5-43ff35620897", artifact_path="trained_model_outputs/_samples.json",dst_path="./outputs")


